# Tess4j api is not reading pdf file accurately

Tags: java, pdf, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am about to read pdf file with tess4j in java, it is working perfectly but unfortunately in my pdf, every thing is in table format and tess4j is reading all rows except following two  rows are **Currency ZAR and Amount 4.00**, i don't know what is the reason. below is the table i am missing CURRENCY and AMOUNT rows.

VALUE DATE             (DDMMYY) 21-Dec-14

CURRENCY               ZAR

AMOUNT                 1.88

ORDERING INSTITUTION   NEDBANK LIMITED 
                        NEDSZAJJ

INTERMEDIARY           HSBC BANK
                        HSBCBB22

COMMENTS               RBCD

can you please help me to solve this problem

You can find a sample PDF here [MT210_changed_123.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrweyx91n7osual/MT210_changed_123.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: If you want any help, you should share the PDF in question (via some serious file sharing service, e.g. Dropbox or google drive  public shares) and your pivotal code.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrweyx91n7osual/MT210_changed_123.pdf?dl=0

Comment: hi you can find pdf file in above link